# Dock for ThinkPad Yoga 370 / X1

Tags: thinkpad, dock, thunderbolt, usb-c

Is there a docking station which works for ThinkPad Yoga 370 (or the newest X1), please?

*ThinkPad USB 3.0 Basic/Pro/Ultra Dock*, *ThinkPad USB-C Dock*, *ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock* seem to work on Windows, but according to old resources are not fully supported on Linux (ethernet via dock, USB-C/Thunderbolt by itself...).

P.S. I do not mind waiting a few months till a new kernel/driver is released.

Comment: I am still looking too. I have the x380 pluged into the new usbc dock but the external monitor does not work.

Comment: I experience the same monitor issue on USB-C Dock. Maybe it is related to KDE as @dbahn25 suggests on [Lenovo Forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/USB-C-dock-amp-Linux/m-p/3781123/highlight/true#M9869).